# Handling Checkboxes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, checkbox

I have a component that I am writing that handles the days and hours of the week.The main component that passes in a state of time to the sub component "UpdateHours" passes in the days of the week in an object, all the days are set to a default of true. So all the Check boxes are all checked by default. When I click on the day, the object is updated to false on my console but the check box remains checked even when the value is set to false. A curious part, when I click my button on the page that updates the backend the boxes I checked false become unchecked.

The object being passed through from the parent component

```
function handleAddNewHour() {
    var uid = generateUUID();
    var newHour = {
      mon: true,
      tue: true,
      wed: true,
      thu: true,
      fri: true,
      sat: true,
      sun: true,
      start: 0,
      end: 0,
      service_type: "all",
      id: uid
    };

    setTime(newHour);
  }



 {time != null ? (<UpdateHour time={time} setTimeChange={handleTimeUpdate}/>) : (  "" )}
```

The element on UpdateHours.js

```
 <div className="newHoursDay" onClick={() => handleDayChange("mon")}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="new_hours_mon"
              checked={props.time.mon}
              value={props.time.mon}
              onChange={() => handleDayChange("mon")}
            />
            <label>Mon</label>
          </div>
```

Here are the functions

```
  function handleDayChange(day) {
    let hourData = props.time;
    hourData[day] = !props.time[day];
    props.setTimeChange(hourData);

  }

  function handleServiceChange(serviceType) {
    props.time[serviceType] = serviceTypes;
    setState({});
  }
```

This function calls my function that updates the firestore database with the new object

```
function handleSave() {
    var hoursData = {
      hours: {}
    };
    if (typeof store.hours !== "undefined") {
      hoursData.hours = store.hours;
    }
    hoursData.hours[props.time.id] = {};
    Object.keys(props.time).forEach(prop => {
      if (prop === "id") {
        hoursData.hours[props.time.id][prop] = props.time[prop];
      }
    });
    changeStoreData(hoursData);

    //updatestore
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `onClick` for the `div`?

Comment: I have but that makes everything unresponsive, It was throwing me an error, but I just tried to replicate that and now it just makes the whole checkbox unresponsive

Comment: Are the updated props being passed properly to `UpdateHours.js`? Like can you log the updated value(s)  in the render/above the return statement for the `UpdateHours` component?

Comment: It looks like yes, I put a console.log at the top above the return and when I click on the save button I see the values I expect to see

Comment: When you log it what does `props.time.mon` look like when you log it? I assume it's true/false but I just wanted to verify.

Comment: end: 0
fri: true
id: "d59cd082-9b48-4fd7-bc7b-59a9244220ac"
mon: true
sat: true
service_type: "all"
start: 0
sun: true
thu: false
tue: false
wed: true

Comment: wow that is a mess, but yes it's true and false

Comment: Hm that's strange. Try storing it as a variable before the return. Write something like `var checked = props.time.mon` and then for the checkbox set the `checked` value equal to that new `checked` variable.

Comment: Ok so that didn't quite work, The checkbox still wouldn't change, but when I explicitly change checked to false (the variable) the box is unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your `handleDayChange` function, you're updating the value directly on your `time` prop. It's worth noting that props in React should be read-only (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only). The reason being, React does not do a deep comparison, but is only checking whether the *reference* has changed.

Because `props.time` is an object, when you call `let hourData = props.time` you're setting `hourData` equal to the reference to `props.time`. When you then update values on `hourData`, it's actually updating `props.time`, and when you pass `hourData` to `props.setTimeChange` it's passing the reference to `props.time`. Since the reference hasn't changed, React doesn't know that the object has mutated, and therefore doesn't render again with the updated values.

Hopefully it's as simple as updating your `handleDayChange` function to create a new object rather than mutating `props.time`:

```js
function handleDayChange(day) {
    const hourData = {
        ...props.time,
        [day]: !props.time[day]
    };
    props.setTimeChange(hourData);

}
```